# How to customize the SharePoint list view page

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, search, list-view, modern-experience

I wanted help to customize this look for better presentation, the search option is required here with a clear button.

It would be helpful if we can implement search and clear buttons for ease of using and also is it possible to change the page design to present the view with a modern look?

[image]

Comment: Are you using modern team site or classic experience site in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Online, you can change the list experience to **Modern experience** using below steps:

1. Go to **List Settings**.
2. Click **Advanced settings**.
3. Scroll down and go to **List experience**.
4. Select **New experience**.
5. Click **OK**.

[How to change list and library default experience in SharePoint online](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/sharepoint-change-default-experience/)

This way you will have a modern experience for your list view. Also, you will get the **modern search box** which has a clear button inside it.

[image]